# If $4$ distinct integers $a, b, c, d$ are randomly selected from $n$ distinct integers, what is the probability that $a \lt b \lt c \lt d$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, trees, decision-trees

> a. If $i$ distinct integers $r_1, r_2, \ldots,r_i$, i $\leq n$, are randomly selected (one after other) from n distinct integers, what is the probability that $r_1 < r_2 < \cdots < r_i$?
>
> b. Does the probability you got in part *a* of the question change if < is replaced with $\leq$?

I know that a question similar to part '*a*' of this  question can be solved using the concept of *Decision tree that orders the elements of the list*, an application of which is to *analyse the complexity of comparison-based sorting algorithm*.

I came across a solution to part '*a*' of the question that says the required probability is $C(n, i)/P(n,i)$, which is nothing but equal to the solution of the *Decision tree* based approach, which is $1/i!$.

What I don't understand is this - how $C(n,i)$ is equal to favourable number of outcomes and $P(n,i)$ is equal to total number of outcomes?

---

Figure: A decision tree for sorting three distinct elements.

[image: A decision tree for sorting three distinct elements]

*Image taken from Discreet Mathematics and its Applications by Kenneth Rosen*

Comment: What does $P(n,i)$ mean?

Comment: I edited the question. P(n,i) is i-permutation of a set with n elements

Comment: Yes. I suppose $C(n,i)$ means $\binom n i = \frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$. I don't know what you mean by $P(n,i)$.

Comment: hint: every possible order of them is equally probable.

Comment: Not $1/n!$, but $1/i!$.

Comment: @Tavish Yes it should be 1/i!

Answer (score 1):

$C(n,i)$ chooses $i$ integers from $n$ integers without giving importance to their order. Given such a set of $i$ integers, we can first order them in ascending order, and then assign the corresponding values to $r_1,r_2\dots r_i$ so that $r_1 \lt r_2 \lt \dots \lt r_i $.

$P(n,i)$ counts the total ways. Why? The number of choices for $r_1$ is $n$, for $r_2$ is $n-1$ and so on. That gives $$n(n-1)(n-2)\dots (n-i+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-i)!} = P(n,i) $$

Answer (score 1):

For any given choice of $i$ integers from among the $n$ possible integers, only one permutation of these $i$ integers produces a valid result, because the $n$ integers are distinct.

There are $C(n,i)$ such choices of $i$ integers from among $n$ integers, and $P(n,i)$ permutations of $i$ integers from among $n$ integers.

Comment: Please, can you also explain it using a decision tree based approach.

Comment: What is a decision tree based approach?

Comment: suppose i is fixed to 3 and we don't have to choose i from among n distinct integers, then  I can just make a binary tree and count the number of leaves which gives me the total number of outcomes. Among them only one is favourable. I am trying to extend this approach to when we have to choose i from among n distinct integers

Comment: Do you want to count the number of solutions or devise an algorithm? I am still confused. Do you want to count it 'by cases'? You can totally do that, it's just more cumbersome.

Comment: No, I don't want to devise an algorithm(write code or anything), I just want to convince myself by the graphical approach of constructing a tree. Something similar to the notorious "Monty Hall Three-Door Puzzle", that can be explained by constructing a tree.  I just don't know how to construct one here.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with constructing the tree?

Comment: I am stuck at the approach that I should take to begin constructing tree with the added complexity that we have to randomly select i distinct integers from n distinct integers.  If we have already chosen a b c d, then I can construct one.

Comment: What are a b c d? This is so confusing. $$$$
The tree will just be... large. Start at the root, where no choices have been made. Each time you go down a branch, you choose an integer that you have not yet chosen in that path, and set the node's value to that integer. Going down a path from the root, $r_1$ will be the value of the first child, $r_2$ will be the value of the second child, and so on.

Comment: I apologise for confusion. I added an Image of a decision tree for clarity. By a b c d, I meant 4 distinct integers under consideration for sorting. We make a decision tree similar to the one in image and count the number of leaves that turn out to be 4!

Comment: Construct a tree for $i$ integers (rather than $n$). Any distinct $i$ integers will produce the same tree, up to relabeling. Then multiply the result be the distinct number of ways of choosing $i$ integers from among $n$ distinct integers. Which is basically the same as we did.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1:

If you take letters $a, b, c, d$, there are $4!$ orders possible.
$a \lt b \lt c \lt d$ is one of them.

Hence the desired probability $\displaystyle  = \frac{1}{4!}$

Approach 2: Place **( $ \ $ a $ \ $ b $ \ $ c $ \ $ d $ \ $)** first, and now start placing other $(n-4)$ letters in between. The first letter of $(n-4)$ has $5$ places available. Once you place the first letter, you now have $6$ places for the next letter and so on.

Total number of favorable arrangements $ = 5 \times 6 \times 7 ... \times n$. Divide this by $n!$ which is total number of unrestricted arrangements.

Approach 3 (same as approach 2): As the order is fixed, you cannot permute (a b c d) so the number of arrangements are $\frac{n!}{4!}$. Divide this by $n!$

Comment: Please, can you also explain it using a decision tree based approach

Comment: Can your decision tree not have different orders of a b c d? If you count it should give you $24$ and one of them is the order that you want?

Comment: Yes, I agree. But then we have already chosen a b c d and then go on to construct the tree. So the total ordering possible is 4! and only one among them is the favourable outcome . My question is that how to construct a decision tree so that when we count the total outcomes, it turns out to be $P(n,i)$ and the favourable outcomes is $C(n, i)$

Comment: OK understand. For a general case like this, won't decision tree be very cumbersome? But at the same time, I acknowledge that I do not use decision tree much so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The probability does change if you replace $<$ with $\leq$ and you're sampling from your set of $n$ distinct integers with replacement.

In this situation, the number of unordered samples of size $i$ becomes ${n+i-1 \choose i}$ while the number of ordered samples of size $i$ is $n^i$.

So the probability that $r_1\leq \ldots \leq r_i$ equals $\frac{{n+i-1 \choose i}}{n^i}$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for solving $a)$ and $b)$ is the following:

$a)$ (I assume the numbers are selected without replacement):
Each sequence of $i$ numbers can be represented as a vector in $\{0,1\}^n$ with exactly $i$ coordinates being equal to $1$. For example, let $n=9$ and $i=4$, then $$1< 4< 5<8 \longleftrightarrow \{1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0\}\\ 2<3<7<9 \longleftrightarrow \{0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0\}\\ 5<6<7<8\longleftrightarrow \{0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0\}$$ This way, in order to create any feasible sequence we only have to choose the $i$ coordinates where the $1$s will be placed. This lead us to a probability of $$\dfrac{\dbinom{n}{i}}{n!/(n-i-1)!}.$$

$b)$ (I assume the numbers are selected with replacement):
In order to solve $b)$ all we have to do is to represent each sequence as a vector in $\{0,\ldots,n\}^i$ and count how many of these vectors have the sum of their coordinates equal to $i$. For example, let $n=9$ and $i=4$, then $$1\leq 2\leq 2\leq 6 \longleftrightarrow \{1,2, 0,0,0,1,0,0,0\}\\3\leq 3\leq 3\leq 3 \longleftrightarrow \{0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0\}\\ 1\leq 4\leq 8\leq 9 \longleftrightarrow \{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1\}$$ By using stars and bars we get that the probability of having a favourable sequence is $$\dfrac{\dbinom{n+i-1}{i}}{n^i}.$$

Comment: It is strange to assume that the procedure differs in the case b). In any case the given answer is wrong. Just check for $n=3,i=2$.

Comment: @user The number of $n-$ tuples whose sum is $i$ equals ${n + i -1 \choose i}$, not ${n+i-1 \choose i-1}$. If we have $n=3,i=2$ then $${n+i-1 \choose i}=6$$ which corresponds to the six numbers $$11,12,13,22,23,33$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling Yes, you correctly found the error.

Comment: @MatthewPilling True, thanks for the comment!

Comment: @user I changed the assumption since $r$ could not be repeated in $a)$ but it could happen in $b)$. Anyways, the problem is not 100% accurate to me. It could be explained better imo.